# Is this company claiming to be a broker a Scam?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, scams, broker

I am very new to trading, so please take it easy with me. Recently I was searching online and doing independent research and met a new friend who recommended https://fortistrad.com/en/ for me. I installed their recommended trading platform i.e. MT4 and I was given a $100K virtual fund to trade in order to understand how the app works. I liked it so far.

However, I am still sceptical about the authenticity of this broker. For me to start real trading, they request I do a bank transfer to a given account in HongKong and the funds will be deposited into my MT4 account. However, whenever I browse their website, I do find it difficult to trust them. There are no public reviews about them online making it difficult for any independent verification.

Can someone please advise me on this?

Comment: Why in the world would you take a chance when there are plenty of known legitimate brokers that offer the same services?

Comment: Check with regulatory agencies where the broker is located.

Comment: Even if this is a legitimate broker what are you going to do if you ever get into a disagreement with them? Can you afford to hire legal representation in Hong Kong? Unless you can afford international legal representation you should stick to companies that have an actual presence in your own country so that you have recourse to the law if things go sideways.

Comment: Why would you take financial advice from someone you just met?

Comment: `MT4` has been discussed in other questions on Money.SE, several with the [scams] tag: https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=MT4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This company is clearly a scam. I recently got talking to a Chinese girl on Tinder who tried to persuade me to trade bitcoin with them. She claimed to have studied in my home town and to be in Hong Kong due to Covid19. But after days of chatting it became clear that she could not answer any questions about her stay here. She got very coy when I tried to move the conversation to any other topic. I believe there is a team out there targeting social media and dating sites trying to take advantage of people by using this story. Beware.

Answer (score 6):

This is all but certainly a scam. The site was registered just a few weeks ago, on 2020-05-19. It's using a name confusingly similar to the legitimate company, Fortis Trading. Their website contains numerous red flags, such as the bizarre formatting on their ["common problem"](https://fortistrad.com/en/read.jsp?id=16)[sic] page. At least some of their content appears to be taken from newdc-fx.com, a similar site now shut down. For example, compare [this](https://fortistrad.com/en/read.jsp?id=18) with [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HEY4qJm1n1MJ:www.newdc-fx.com/en/read.jsp%3Fid%3D18%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca); identical content, same telephone number, etc.

Comment: Additionally, consider your PC compromised. Your copy of MT4 is likely trojanized. Don't use it for banking or online shopping until it has been thoroughly disinfected.